# Glass Mapper: Cast<MyClass>(myItem) returning null, while previously was correctly returning an instance of MyClass

Tags: glass-mapper

I have the following legacy code wrote by my predecessors:

`var formSection = SitecoreContextFactory.Default.GetSitecoreContext().Cast<FormSection>(section);`

`FormSection` is a simple class with getters and setters whose names match those of the Sitecore fields on the item `section` (EDIT: this class has no [SitecoreField] decorators). `section` is an instance of a Sitecore Item (of type `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`) previously retrieved from the DB.

This code has always worked fine, and it's running in production. It has since started to *silently fail* (by returning *null*), and while I can replace it with foolproof code I would rather address the root cause and understand what caused it to *start failing*.

Comment: Please check the item version in the context language, if exists or not. Add one version if doesn't exist.

Comment: @GuptaSandeepkumar it does, it's the first thing I checked.